# MySQL table only submitting first time from EXT js + PHP entry

Tags: php, mysql, extjs

I am having a problem with my MySQL.

I have everything setup and all is well, but when I submit my form it will only work if the table is completely empty. It will not submit another entry if there is already information stored in the table.

here is the mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE student
(StudentID int NOT NULL,
StudentFirst varchar(30),
StudentLast varchar(30), 
StudentEmail varchar(254),
StudentPhone varchar(12),
StudentDOB date,
DateStarted date, 
LessonID int,
StudentAddress varchar(50), 
StudentCity varchar(30), 
StudentState char(2), 
StudentZip varchar(10), 
MusicInterest text);
alter table student add constraint StudentPK primary key AUTO_INCREMENT (StudentID); 
alter table student add constraint LessonFK foreign key (LessonID) references lesson(LessonID);
```

This is my PHP

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
switch($_REQUEST['action']){
        case 'submit_student':
            $first = $_REQUEST['StudentFirst'];
            $last = $_REQUEST['StudentLast'];
            $email = $_REQUEST['StudentEmail'];
            $phone = $_REQUEST['StudentPhone'];
            $dob = $_REQUEST['StudentDOB'];
            $datestarted = $_REQUEST['DateStarted'];
            $lessonid = $_REQUEST['LessonID'];
            $address = $_REQUEST['StudentAddress'];
            $city = $_REQUEST['StudentCity'];
            $state = $_REQUEST['StudentState'];
            $zip = $_REQUEST['StudentZip'];
            $musicinterest = $_REQUEST['MusicInterest'];


            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into student (StudentFirst, StudentLast, StudentEmail,  StudentPhone, StudentDOB, DateStarted, LessonID, StudentAddress, StudentCity, StudentState, StudentZip,MusicInterest) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt -> bindParam(1,$first);
            $stmt -> bindParam(2,$last);
            $stmt -> bindParam(3,$email);
            $stmt -> bindParam(4,$phone);
            $stmt -> bindParam(5,$dob);
            $stmt -> bindParam(6,$datestarted);
            $stmt -> bindParam(7,$lessonid);
            $stmt -> bindParam(8,$address);
            $stmt -> bindParam(9,$city);
            $stmt -> bindParam(10,$state);
            $stmt -> bindParam(11,$zip);
            $stmt -> bindParam(12,$musicinterest);
            $stmt -> execute();
        break;
```

and my EXTJs

```
function addStudent(){
        Ext.Ajax.request ({
        url: 'inc/template.php',
        params: {action: 'submit_student',

                                 StudentFirst:firstNameTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentLast:lastNameTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentEmail: emailTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentPhone:phoneNumberTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentDOB:Ext.util.Format.date(dateOfBirth.getValue(), 'Y-m-d'),
                                 DateStarted:dateStarted.getValue(),
                                 LessonID:dayTypeCombo.getValue(),
                                 StudentAddress:streetTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentCity:cityTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentState:stateTextField.getValue(),
                                 StudentZip:zipTextField.getValue(),
                                 MusicInterest:musicInterest.getValue()
                                 },
                                 method: 'POST',
        });
    tabPanel.activate(studentGrid);
    tabPanel.activate(scheduleGrid);
    clearStudentForm();
```

I have no idea why it only submits one time. It is really baffling. It shows the post in firebug.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create a test first that is creating a table with just a single column for starters and trying out if you can get it to work? Then add a second column which is not a primary key and try again. And then add the foreign key? Those problems are normally solve quicklier on the computer itself by trying because you can actually execute this.

Comment: Is `Ext JS` sending request to `php` file or not?

Comment: Also I would say you can greatly improve your code by adding error handling. If something does not work in adding a row, mysql normally tells why, e.g. if a key constaint is violated or something similar.

Comment: @hakre that is a good idea. I'll remember that.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yes, it is getting the request from the action/url

Comment: @hakre I deleted my StudentID primary key, and it works just fine. What does that mean?

Comment: @hakre I was trying to force the database to auto increment the studentid for me but it was not doing it. any suggestions?

Comment: @RyanCox: That is broadly worded. You can rest assured that auto-incremental primary keys in mysql *work*. So the only idea this gives me firsthand is that you're doing something wrong. My first assumption is because of the secondary key in there, probably you have a violation there. Did you verify the error message(s)?

Comment: Also quick scan of Mysql manual suggests you need to set the PK NOT NULL

Comment: do you have any `Relation` on `studentid` with other tables?

Comment: @hakre I totally assume it is me. Not MySQL :) I'm still learning. I thought I had the PK set not null up top where it says StudentID int NOT NULL

Comment: @Amir I WILL not at the moment.

Comment: Hmm, did you consider my tip on trouble-shooting doing this step-by step? you can even try with a database tool like phpmyadmin to run the queries without any PHP code, that also shows you the messages this produces.

Comment: @hakre I will try the queries out!

Comment: is `studentid` primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `AUTO-INCREMENT` statement at

`alter table student add constraint StudentPK primary key AUTO_INCREMENT (StudentID);`

Also i think, you should use this syntax for multiple columns. for one column use

```
CREATE TABLE student
(StudentID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
StudentFirst varchar(30),
...
```

Comment: Your syntax helped so much!

I used

CREATE TABLE student
(StudentID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
StudentFirst varchar(30),

and it worked like a charm!